# How do I add a line of code to help debug Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a code that is supposed to show an image and refresh that image every 1 second.  I have two .aspx pages, one saves the new image to a file, the other is to display the new image.  It is not refreshing with the javascript code.  it will display the new image if I hit F5 or refresh the page from the address bar, but not with the code.  I cannot debug because I do not have administrative privileges on this computer (at work) so I want to try to add something like "num = num+1" and then display num in a textbox.  I want to do this to see if my code is even entering the javascript at all.

Here is the code for the viewer page with the javascript:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style="height: 60px"> 
<%--<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"  /> --%>   
<img src="/video.aspx" id="the_image" alt="" />


  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

      function refreshImage() {
          objIMG = document.getElementById('the_image');
          objIMG.src = objIMG.src.substr(0, objIMG.src.indexOf('&nocache=')); +'&nocache=' + Math.random();
      }

      $(document).ready(function () {
          setInterval(refreshImage(), 1000);

                })

</script>

    <br />
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

If you are interested here is the code to save the new image to a file:

```
namespace PlayVideo
{
 public partial class Video : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This is where I originally had the function that saves the new image.
    //string saveTo = @"location to save new image";
    //FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(saveTo, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

    using(FileStream fs = File.Open(@"C:Location of file", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
        ReadWriteStream(fs, writeStream);
        }

    Response.Clear();
    Response.TransmitFile("~/images/test.jpg");



}

// readStream is the stream you need to read
// writeStream is the stream you want to write to
private void ReadWriteStream(Stream readStream, Stream writeStream)
{
    int Length = 256;
    Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
    int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
    // write the required bytes
    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
    }
    readStream.Close();
    writeStream.Close();
}
```

}

I don't really no javascrict, I got the code I'm using online.  I want to just add that debug line.  Can someone help?  I'm using Visual Studio 2010, if you're wondering.

Comment: Take a look to [Debugging JavaScript in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) to see if helps to debug that method.

Comment: Consider changing `setInterval(refreshImage(), 1000);` to `setInterval(refreshImage, 1000);` The first argument for `setInterval` is a reference to the code to call, not a call to the code. I am not sure if this will make any difference.

Comment: @DaveB that IS the error...and it WILL make a difference.

Comment: it was setInterval(refreshImage,1000), but that didn't work so I tried setInterval(refreshImage(),1000) and forgot to change it back for this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log(yourData);
```

and before running it press F12 and go to Console tab. Using Firefox with Firebug plugin would help too.

Comment: In fact, after reviewing your question, if you want to know if your code is executed, you can place some 
alert(1); and alert(2) to see where it stops. If the alert doesn't pop, then you know your code is not executed

Comment: Before your function, at the begining of your function and at the end of it. You can also alert some data. By example: alert(num); . The more you put alert(); in your code, the faster you'll be able to find where your code stops running.

Comment: I put alert(1) right under <script type="text/javascript"> and nothing happens.  Does that mean it is never going in to the javascript code?

Comment: Not really. In your code, I would put it inside your function refreshImage(). Also, don't forget to add a ; to your $(document).function( //YOUR CODE }); <---- your ;

Comment: That did help, I was able to fix it.  But this javascript doesn't do what I want it to do.  The new picture is saved only when video.aspx page is loaded.  The picture is displayed in viewer.aspx.  Is there a way to reload video.aspx without reloading viewer.aspx?  This javascript seems to only refresh the image on viewer.aspx, but since the new picture never got saved the image on viewer.aspx is just the same picture.

Comment: The function refreshImage is in document.ready. This means it will load one time when the page is done loading. To make it reload every time you do an action, you will have to call the function in an event listener. If you want to know how to use the eventListeners with Javascript you should ask another question. If this helped you, please confirm my answer so others will be able to refer to it.

Comment: I confirmed your answer.  I will  have to look up event listeners.  Do you have a link that might be close to what I'm looking to do?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp
If you are using a lot of Javascript, you should take a look at JQuery
http://api.jquery.com/
If you use JQuery you would have something like $('#yourElement').on("yourEvent",function(){
});

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browser you are using to view the page, it probably has a developer toolbar or a set of dev tools built in. You can use this to debug your javascript without needing any elevated privileges.

You can access them in IE but hitting F12.